# How to find duplicate Pocket articles?

Tags: pocket

I noticed that sometimes Pocket saves artcles even if they are already present in my account.

I don't know the technicalities about how this can happen, but I'd like to know if there is a way to find those duplicates and keep just one copy.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you found a solution by now, but here is a script which scans for "?" after a / in case you saved it across multiple social media channels:

https://keepingitclassless.net/2015/01/remove-duplicates-from-pocket-list